# how to replicate this postgres command in coredata?

Tags: ios, core-data

How do I replicate following Postgres command in ios core-data ?

```
crypt($password, gen_salt('md5'))
```

User accounts table is downloaded from backend server. Passwords have been generated using the above **Postgres** command in the server.
Now I need to compare the password from the iPhone to authenticate users when app is offline. Does anyone know how do the same hashing in iPhone ?

Note: I know how just convert to md5 in iOS. The question is not about that.

Comment: Alright, sorry, I was a bit too quick to point to the existing answer.